How do I explain why my planet has only one continent?
My fictional world has only one continent. I don't know how to explain that fact. Is there a plausible science explanation for a planet to have only one continent?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Earth used to only have one continent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea

@Rhymehouse: There was Rodinia 1 billion years ago, then there was Pannotia 500 million years ago, then there was Pangaea 250 million years ago, and there will be Pangaea Proxima some 200 million years in the future...

The narrator explaining to us? ("One big continent") Or characters describing to each other? ("The land")

I assume you did basic research and discovered it's perfectly natural for a planet too have only one continent, as Earth did several times, and so this is a writing/story question rather than one of worldbuilding. FTC.

Earth presented with a single landmass during ~1Bn yrs in total (Columbia+Rodinia+Pangaea), 20-25% of its timeline. Definitely not a blink of the eye on the geological timescale.

One continent on a planet is fairly plausible. It does however introduce a myriad of problems, such as like the middle of the continent being deadland, and other rather nasty side effects that would limit the growth of your civilization. I would advise makign your singular continent a chaotic blotch like Europe, not an uniform mass like say, Africa. Maximize the number of bays, isthmuses, peninsulas etc, and maybe even slap an inland sea somewhere in it.

By the nature of plate tectonics, continents break apart and reform over periods of geological time. If you want to provide an explanation for there only being one continent on your world, you can place the evolution of intelligent life around the time that the continents are converging.

From just a physical world perspective, I can think of two primary reasons why there would only be one continent
Pangaea Map
As stated in previous answers, the world's tectonics are in a Pangaea phase.  At this time, the plates of the world have organized into one giant continent.  In millions of years, they may split apart and come back together again but for now, one land.
Water World
In short, there is only one continent above sea level.
While there are plates and they do drift, there is only one plate that has enough land above water to count as a continent as we would think of it.  Smaller islands dot the waters where they would make sense to be placed -- likely from volcanoes near plate boundaries for one location
Where this differs from the Pangaea idea is that there was never multiple continents unless the sea level happened to be lower in a previous age.
For Your Consideration
From a story boarding reason, consider if there is a reason to decide definitively that the world has a single continent.  Is there only one major landmass because it explains something else about the world?   Or is there only one continent because the forces in the story only know about a single continent?

People just don't know about the other continents
A narrator can only tell us about what they know about. If the world objectively has 2, to 10 continents, unless those are accessible or known about, then they are virtually irrelevant to the story. All you need is a reason why nobody has managed to observe the other continent and live to tell about it.
Maybe the other continents are protected by magic and if you are not born on them, just seeing them is lethal. Or crossing the oceans is so hard and lethal with the weather there, that nobody ever got over to or from another continent.

If you're just looking for a word, most people should understand what "supercontinent" means- basically, all the landmasses have come together over a long period of time and formed into one larger continent.
However, if you mean a world that only has one continent, but the continent isn't the size of several continents smashed together, I would say explaining it as you already have ("there is only one [normal-sized] continent"), or maybe you could say "my world is monocontinental"...
I don't think "monocontinental" is technically likely to show up in a dictionary, but it properly describes the situation and most people should understand it; "mono-" just means there's only one of something.

If it's for a story and you need to explain to people that there is only one continent then if you are using a narrator perspective you can just state that there is only one continent. If not then a character might tell a story to explain that they have sailed all around the worlds oceans without seeing land. Or someone might recount key information about such voyages from a book they had read.
This should work, unless there are large amounts of ice at the poles in which case it would be very difficult to tell if a mass of ice was atop a continent island or sea with any certainty.
